# loopj multiple async requests not returning in signed APK

Tags: android, android-async-http, loopj

I have an app that requires a lot of async requests, for which I am using the loopj asynchttpclient library.

After login to a service, many requests get made, someone loading 5-10 images at one time, and a couple JSON requests, all made around the same time. I never had an issue in all of my debug testing over the last several months. But after building a signed APK and installing, when multiple requests get ran simultaneously (in the above description) - the requests stop returning anything. None of the call backs are called. The server is receiving the requests and returning, but the async http callbacks never get called.

I have read that if all the callbacks are not implemented its possible they won't call, but I have implemented them all including the deprecated ones and still no luck.

Any reason why this would happen? I am kind of late in the game and am trying to avoid having to switch to an entirely different networking library.

Cheers

Comment: Sometimes this lib bugs here too, dont know why. But if it works in Debug mode, it should work in release mode. Shouldn't make any differences.. Also, are you sure implemented all ResponseHandlers, such as  JSONResponseHandler? Inside JSONResponseHandler, have you implemented all `onSuccess` methods?

Comment: It turns out I was missing an extra onSuccess and and extra onFailure - but adding them did not solve the problem. I also removed the multiple network calls at one time, but same result. Works fine in debug, but stops returning callbacks after the 3rd call or so in the signed apk